# How to do Localization and Navigation in 3D using octomap from RGBD-SLAM?

Tags: slam, navigation, rgbd6dslam, octomap, octomap-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ROS- electric. Now, I am able to built a octomap with the help of RGBDSLAM package. The map is in format '.bt'. Is there any packages available for doing localization and navigation in 3D using this octomap?

Note:localization should be done without using laser.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41105/how-to-do-localization-and-navigation-in-3d-using-octomap-from-rgbd-slam?/) by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2012-08-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have a 6D localization running in an OctoMap for our humanoid robots. You can find details in the publication ["Humanoid Robot Localization in Complex Indoor Environments"](http://hrl.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/papers/hornung10iros.pdf). It's runnning MCL (particle filtering) and uses ray casting for the sensor model.

The code is now published at http://ros.org/wiki/humanoid_localization

It's mostly designated for humanoid robots and still being polished right now, but I'm sure you can use much of the sensor model code as example.

If you want to implement your own localization, you can use the function [castRay](http://octomap.sourceforge.net/doxygen/classoctomap_1_1OccupancyOcTreeBase.html#afc368d6ff93f40ee33eca3df0b8d1967) in OctoMap.

In terms of map building, planning, and collision checking in an OctoMap look at the [3d_navigation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/3d_navigation) stack and the publication ["Navigation in Three-Dimensional Cluttered Environments
for Mobile Manipulation"](http://hrl.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/papers/hornung12icra_3Dnav.pdf).

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on 2012-08-10**:
yes, I am interested and you can publish the codes. Is it possible to ray casting with kinect or LASER is necessary?

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-08-10**:
OctoMap doesn't care about your sensor. You can raycast with any distance sensor, all it needs is a direction and an origin. The sensor model may be a little harder to tweak though.

**Comment by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on 2012-08-10**:
I have a kinect but it can't measure the objects lesser than 1.2m. Is there any solutions for that? Also, I saw one more package(3d_navigation) just now which is maintained by you. Both are same?

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-08-10**:
The minimum range should be around 0.7m, but that is the general problem with such a sensor. I added 3d_navigation to my answer, they serve different purposes. You will have to read the papers for the details.

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-09-25**:
The code is now public, I edited my answer. It's still being polished and finalized for point clouds, but it may give you some idea.

**Comment by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on 2012-09-26**:
Thank you very much

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-09-28**:
If your question is answered, please mark the answer as correct (checkmark).

**Comment by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on 2012-10-10**:
I marked this as a correct answer long back, but for some reasons the checkmark is not working in my browser properly.